# Countdown until matching digits

Tags: c++

Write a program in C++ that takes in an integer in the range 20-98 as input. The output is a countdown starting from the integer, and stopping when both output digits are identical.

Ex: If the input is:

93
the output is:

93 92 91 90 89 88

I'm having trouble with how I would compare both digits to see if they're identical.

Comment: `if (digit1 == digit2) { ... code ... }` - does this help? If not, please clarify your question.

Comment: If both digits are identical, the current number will be a multiple of 11 and therefore `i % 11 == 0`, assuming `i` is your counter.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `/` and `%`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  int i{};
  std::cin >> i;
  if (i > 98 || i < 20) {
    return -1;
  }

  while (i / 10 != i % 10) {
    std::cout << i-- << ' ';
  } 
  std::cout << i << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    int i;
    std::cin >> i;

    do { cout <<i<< endl; } while (i--%11);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: One can write some crazy unreadable stuff with c++. I like it :D

Comment: That is far from "crazy unreadable".... it can get way worse than that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Split the number into the digits (LHS and RHS) and then compare if both are same.

To get the LHS use the divide operator (`/`).

To get the RHS use the mod operator (`%`)

Example pseudo code:

```
int iNum = 98;

// iRHS will have 9
int iRHS = iNum % 10;

// iLHS will have 8
int iLHS = iNum/10;

if (iRHS == iLHS) {
 // Both digits are same.
}
```

Hope this helps.
ps: I did not compile the code